# VC++ inherit from abstract class

Tags: class, visual-c++, abstract

I have two classes like this:

```
// parent.h

class Parent {
    public:
        virtual void Method() = 0;
}
```

and

```
//child.h

#include "parent.h"

class Child : public Parent {
    public:
        Child();
        ~Child();
        virtual void Method();
}
```

---

```
//child.cpp

#include "child.h"

Child::Child() { }
Child::~Child() { }

void Child::Method() { }
```

+

```
void main() {
    Parent* p = new Child();
}
```

This works fine with g++ on Linux, but when I try to apply the same pattern in VS 2010 I get:

```
error C2259: 'Child' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you compiling the exact same files with g++ and VS2010? Sure it's not a typo? g++ behavior is correct.

Comment: i reassembled the files into a new project, and everything was ok thist time.. so I guess there was a typo somewhere. You were right

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `public:` before your function signature in the header file.  g++ might be interpreting it as a private function.

Comment: It is public, I mis-wrote, also there is also a constructor and destructor definition in the header file